# Inconsistent randomization in array

Tags: c++, arrays, random

Basically, I have a 6x6 board. I created a function that's supposed to place three X's on random coordinates on the board.

```
const int size = 6;

char board[6][6] = {0};  //this is actually somewhere else, but I included it here for clarity

char enemies[3] = {'X','X','X'};

void setup(char board[6][6]){

bool valid = false;  //sets initial bool value to false

for (int x = 0; x <= 2; ++x){
    do{
    int a = rand() % size;
    int b = rand() % size;
    if (board[a][b] == 0){
    board[a][b] = enemies[x];
    valid = true;      
        }
    }while(!valid);  //if the value is false, redo until an empty board space is found 
}
```

(I included srand(time(NULL)) in the main function as well)

It works, but only sometimes. Sometimes it generates 3 randomly placed X's, and sometimes only 2. I want it to generate 3 every single time. I have been over it a million times, trying minor variations and corrections, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I included a condition for it to only place enemies[x] if the board is blank (board[a][b] == 0), and yet it sometimes only places 2 X's for some reason.

Comment: In order to identify the problem, you should step through this line-by-line in a debugger, paying close attention to the values of all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first X is placed, `valid` remains true for all subsequent iterations of the `for` loop, even if a valid square hasn't been found.

I changed the iteration variable to `i` (using `x` to mean something other than an ordinal when you're using 2d coordinates is just confusing), and fixed your inner retry loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
    // loop until we find a valid coordinate
    while(true) {
        int a = rand() % size; 
        int b = rand() % size;
        if (board[a][b] == 0){
            board[a][b] = enemies[i];
            break; // we found one!
        }                                   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting the `valid` flag inside the outer loop.  So, once you've placed the first piece, you do not correctly handle duplicates.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 2; ++x)
{
    valid = false;         // <-- you forgot to do this.
    do
    {
        int a = rand() % size;
        int b = rand() % size;
        if (board[a][b] == 0)
        {
            board[a][b] = enemies[x];
            valid = true;      
        }
    } while(!valid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After each run through the do/while loop you need to reset `valid`.  After the first iteration (when `x` is 0), `valid` will be set to true.  You never reset it back to false, and so on the next iterations (starting with `x` being 1), `valid` will be set to true already.  This means that you might select a random coordinate that you've already marked and then proceed to the next `x` anyway.

That means it's entirely possible that only *one* square will have been marked, but the odds of this are low (1 in 1,225, if my math is correct).